# Is there a way to add a legend for ggplot's alpha?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot with many overlapping points (goes from 2-10). Adding jitter to the points makes it very noisy and unappealing. I like adding a alpha in the aesthetics. However, I'd like to have a legend where a reader can see how many points are overlapping for each of those transparencies. Is there such a way?

```
ggplot(data=mydata,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_point(size=3,shape=2,aes(alpha=1/3))
```

Let's say I use the above code. How would I incorporate a legend for the alpha?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but perhaps just a little bit of jitter with transparency could be not too noisy, but still indicate the number of points.

Comment: You can get the data into GGobi, and use Brush tool over the area where overplotting occurs, hence export display description and play with it in R with `rggobi` and `DescribeDisplay` packages. Or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to fake this. Try it a couple times while varying `alpha`.

```
require(ggplot2)

n = 10000
alpha = 0.01

set.seed(12345)
data = data.frame(replicate(2, rnorm(n)))

dev.new(width=4, height=3)
p = qplot(X1, X2, data=data, alpha=alpha)

fake_scale = scale_alpha('# of overlapping pts', breaks=pretty(c(alpha, 1)), labels=as.character(pretty(c(alpha, 1))/alpha))

p + fake_scale
```

`alpha = 0.1`

[image]

`alpha = 0.01`

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me for some reason (the dots in the legend are all the same darkness). Are you using the developers version of `ggplot2`?

Comment: Hi joran - I don't think so. I'm using ggplot2_0.8.8, plyr_1.4, and R version 2.11.1 under i386-apple-darwin9.8.0. Plots are getting printed to png through the quartz device.

Comment: Ah, ok. Well, it doesn't seem to work on OS X with R 2.13.1 and ggplot2_0.8.9. FYI.

Comment: Ahh yes. Must have closed the loophole that was letting me fake in `alpha=alpha` with a constant value instead of `alpha=I(alpha)`, while still thinking there was a real alpha aesthetic present.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want, but how about geom_hex()?

If you don't discretize (bin) it, I think R would need to calculate the overlapped area and the number of overlappedness(sp?) (which would also depend on point size), and that sounds hard.

```
library(hexbin)

mydata <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
ggplot(data=mydata,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_hex()
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That is almost exactly what I want. If only I could turn the hexagons into circles...

Comment: Good luck getting circles to tile a plane ;)

Comment: ha!
I guess the next best thing to do is just use geom_point but create another count column and set that as size.

Comment: or ?sunflowerplot for more discrete data

Answer (score 0):

Taking cues from other answers, it seems like you may want to bin the x-y points into unique values, and then sum up the number of unique values per each x-y coordinate bin.

Using the fake data from another answer,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

n = 10000

set.seed(12345)
data = data.frame(replicate(2, rnorm(n)))
```

I'm binning by the 1st decimal place, and then counting how many are in each bin

```
data2 <- data %>% mutate(
  x = round(X1,1),  
  y = round(X2,1)
) %>% 
  group_by(x,y) %>%
  tally() %>% 
  dplyr::filter(n<=10) %>% 
  mutate(transp = n/10)
```

I filtered out the biggest bins just for illustration purposes. Now, the `transp` column has the calculation you want, which you can supply to `alpha` and get it in the legend

```
data2 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(alpha = as.factor(transp))) + 
  scale_alpha_discrete(
    "Number of overlapping points",
    labels = 1:10
  )+ 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

pic:

[image]