# Why wont ggplot2 allow me to set a size for each individual point?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a scatter plot. I'd like to scale the size of each point by its frequency. So I've got a frequency column of the same length. However, if I do:

```
... + geom_point(size=Freq)
```

I get this error:

```
When _setting_ aesthetics, they may only take one value. Problems: size
```

which I interpret as all points can only have 1 size. So how would I do what I want?

Update: data is [here](http://drop.io/txviuge/asset/new-data-csv)
The basic code I used is:

```
dcount=read.csv(file="New_data.csv",header=T)
ggplot(dcount,aes(x=Time,y=Counts)) + geom_point(aes(size=Freq))
```

Comment: maybe you could show the data and/or more of the code. Seems like this person had a similar problem: http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/0489a702f3afc83b

Comment: of course you could always use geom_hex() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160453/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-legend-for-ggplots-alpha/3161015#3161015

Comment: As of ggplot2's version 2.0.0 you can use `geom_count` and skip creating a new "Freq" column.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17279027/ggplot2-visualizing-counts-of-points-plotted-on-top-of-each-other-stat-bin2d-or.  Also, the data link in this post now redirects to Amazon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, this might be what you're looking for. The code you provided above aggregates the information into four categories. If you don't want that, you can specify the categories with `scale_size_manual()`.

```
sizes <- unique(dcount$Freq)
names(sizes) <- as.character(unique(dcount$Freq))

ggplot(dcount,aes(x=Time,y=Counts)) + geom_point(aes(size=as.factor(Freq))) + scale_size_manual(values = sizes/2)
```

Comment: Thanks much, apeescape! That is exactly what I was looking for.cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried..

```
+ geom_point(aes(size = Freq))
```

Aesthetics are `mapped` to variables in the data with the `aes` function. Check out http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_point.html

Comment: Yes. still does not scale the points according to the frequency. It does create a gradient of point sizes that have nothing to do with the Freq value.

Comment: As always a reproducible example is key

Comment: Sure, I've included a sample of the data and the code in my edited post.

Answer (score 1):

If the code gd047 gave doesn't work, I'd double check that your `Freq` column is actually called `Freq` and that your workspace doesn't have some other object called `Freq`. Other than that, the code should work. How do you know that the scale has nothing to do with the frequency?