# Add legend for alpha when using identity scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm building up a somewhat complex plot and want to specify the alpha for each point manually. I can do this with `scale_alpha_identity`, so far so good. But now I want to add a legend for my alpha scale. Adding a guide to `scale_alpha_identity` doesn't seem to work - I just get an error, even when I try adding breaks and labels as the documentation suggests: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_identity.html.

Minimal example: this produces the plot I'd like, but without a legend.

```
ggplot(data = iris) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, 
                 alpha = Petal.Length / max(Petal.Length))) + 
  scale_alpha_identity()
```

Based on the documentation, I thought this would work but it doesn't:

```
ggplot(data = iris) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, 
                 alpha = Petal.Length / max(Petal.Length))) + 
  scale_alpha_identity(breaks = c(0, 1), labels = c(0, 1), guide = 'legend')
```

I've also tried many other variations: passing `'colorbar'` or `'legend'` directly to the `guide` argument with and without the breaks and labels, passing `guide_legend` or `guide_colorbar` instead of strings - no luck, just different error messages. Adding a fake scale as suggested in [Is there a way to add a legend for ggplot's alpha?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160453/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-legend-for-ggplots-alpha) doesn't work for me because it overrides my identity scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the `limits` in `scale_alpha_identity` you can add a legend via `guides`.

```
ggplot(data = iris) + 
    geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, 
                   alpha = Petal.Length / max(Petal.Length))) + 
    scale_alpha_identity(limits = c(.2, 1)) +
    guides(alpha = guide_legend() )
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2112,
a possible workaround is to use `size` identity function...

```
ggplot(data = iris) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, 
                 alpha = Petal.Length / max(Petal.Length))) + 
  scale_size_identity(guide = 'legend')
```

Comment: This does not work because it does not preserve the identity scale on alpha. To make this more clear, use `alpha = Petal.Length > 2`. If you add scale_alpha_identity back in, the guide disappears again.

Comment: ah, I see that.  Sorry about that.